# Crunch wordlist with different number of words

Tags: password-cracking, dictionary, crunch

I'm trying to generate a wordlist, but I need some help with it. Let's say I execute the command:

```
crunch 1 1 -p cat dog cow
```

Crunch will generate the following:

```
catcowdog
catdogcow
cowcatdog
cowdogcat
dogcatcow
dogcowcat
```

But I also need permutation with 1 and 2 words, so I also need these ones:

```
dog
cat
cow
dogcat
dogcow
catdog
catcow
cowdog
cowcat
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: No idea what `crunch` is but itertools in python would make quick work of this https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

Comment: @Goose I don't think there is an explicit policy, but in general, the more specific to security the tool is, the more on topic it becomes. I^d say crunch questions are on topic, but that is just my two cents.

Answer (score 0):

The [man page](https://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=backtrack-r1-man-pages/crunch) will tell you if it is possible and it states that it is not. It even shows you an example of what it outputs.

You will need to write a script to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the link to the man page in @schroeder's answer you will see example 3:

```
Example 3
crunch 1 6 abcdefg\ 

There is a space at the end of the character string.
In order for crunch to use the space you will need to escape it using the \ character.
In this example you could also put quotes around the letters and not need the \, i.e. "abcdefg ".
Crunch will display a wordlist using the character set abcdefg that starts at a and ends at (6 spaces)
```

Using this method you will get a wordlist with some spaces in it. You can then use `tr` to strip out any spaces in the resulting text file:

```
cat file.txt | tr -d "[:space:]"
```

I believe this will give you what you are after.